# Sublime text regex find and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

In sublime text, I need to replace all instances of:

```
rs('???????')
```

with

```
$rs['??????']
```

(keeping the ??????? part the same). I'm a regex virgin and I've only got as far as locating the regex button on the find and replace panel.

How is this possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find regex:

```
rs\('(.*?)'\)
```

Replace:

```
$rs['$1']
```

Beware that this will expect anything inside the quotes; if it isn't what you need, please tell me :)